# count boolean values that equal between two strings

Tags: java, boolean, weka

I want to count the numbers of true  values between two `String` from my training data, however, the code I implemented only counts the number of instances that are true as opposed to the total sum that are true.

```
//Load dataset
public class DatasetLoading {

  public static Instances loadData(String location) {
    try {
      return DataSource.read(location);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Failed to load data from: " + location);
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String dataLocation = "C:/Users/Emil/Desktop/Machine Learning - Java/Week 1/Arsenal_TRAIN1.arff";
    Instances train = loadData(dataLocation);
    System.out.println(train);
  }
}


public class ForClassifier {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String train1 = "C:/Users/Emil/Downloads/Week 1/Arsenal_TRAIN.arff";

       Instances train = DatasetLoading.loadData(train1);

//train data    
    train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes()-1);

    Classifier Model = (Classifier)new NaiveBayes();
    Model.buildClassifier(train);

    int z=0;
    double x = 0;
    String x2 = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < train.numInstances(); i++)      
    {
         //return data
      String  trueClassLabel = train.instance(i).toString(train.classIndex());
        double predicted = Model.classifyInstance(train.get(i));
       
  
        if(predicted == 0.0) {
            x=predicted;
        }else if (predicted == 1.0){
            x=predicted;

        }else if(predicted == 2.0) {
            x=predicted;
        }
       
        if(x == 0.0) {
        String x1 = "Loss";
        x2 = x1;
        } else if(x == 1.0) {
            String x1 = "Draw";
            x2=x1;
        } else if(x == 2.0) {
            String x1 = "Win";
            x2=x1;
        }
        
       //System.out.println(x2 + "\t"+trueClassLabel + "\t" + x2.equals(trueClassLabel));
        
        if(x2.equals(trueClassLabel)) {
            z++;
            System.out.println(z);
 }}}
```

The output that I get:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
```

The expected output:

```
13
```

I have also tried getting the maximum value however, this returns `1` and not `13`:

```
 if(x2.equals(trueClassLabel)) {
            
            z++;
            Integer[] test2= {z};
            
            for(int j = 0; j<test2.length;j++) {
                if(test2[max] < test2[i]) {
                    max=i;
                    

                }
            }System.out.println(test2[max]);//1
```

@data:

```
@RELATION Arsenal

@ATTRIBUTE Leno  {0,1}
@ATTRIBUTE Tierney   {0,1}
@ATTRIBUTE Saka  {0,1}
@ATTRIBUTE class    {Loss,Draw,Win}
@DATA

1, 0,  0,  Loss
1, 0,  0,  Loss
0, 1,  1,  Draw
1, 0,  1,  Draw
0, 0,  1,  Win
0, 1,  1,  Win
1, 1,  1,  Win
0, 1,  1,  Win
1, 1,  0,  Win
1, 0,  1,  Win
1, 1,  0,  Loss
0, 1,  0,  Draw
1, 1,  0,  Draw
1, 1,  0,  Draw
0, 0,  1,  Win
1, 0,  1,  Win
0, 1,  1,  Win
1, 1,  0,  Win
1, 1,  1,  Win
1, 1,  0,  Win
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing strings, why don't you just compare the numeric prediction obtained from `classifyInstance` with the actual numeric class label from the training data (`train.instance(i).classValue()`)?

Since you didn't post your full code (the `DatasetLoading` class is missing), here is a simple rewrite of your code. The class expects the filename of the dataset to use as the first parameter. This class uses two approaches for evaluating the model: manual comparison of the predictions and using Weka's [Evaluation](https://weka.sourceforge.io/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html) class (which gives you a whole lot more statistics).

```java
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;

public class ForClassifier {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // load dataset
    Instances train = DataSource.read(args[0]);
    train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);

    // build classifier
    Classifier model = new NaiveBayes();
    model.buildClassifier(train);

    // 1. manual evaluation
    System.out.println("manual evaluation");
    int correct = 0;
    int incorrect = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < train.numInstances(); i++) {
      double actual = train.instance(i).classValue();
      double predicted = model.classifyInstance(train.get(i));
      if (actual == predicted)
        correct++;
      else
        incorrect++;
    }
    System.out.println("- correct: " + correct);
    System.out.println("- incorrect: " + incorrect);

    // 2. using Weka's Evaluation class
    System.out.println("Weka's Evaluation");
    Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(train);
    eval.evaluateModel(model, train);
    System.out.println("- correct: " + eval.correct());
    System.out.println("- incorrect: " + eval.incorrect());
  }
}
```

**BTW:** You should never evaluate on the training data, as this will be overly optimistic (the model has already seen all this data!).

Comment: I may have accepted the answer far too quickly, while you have given me very good tips! I still get the same output with a length of 13 numbers as opposed to a final sum of `13`. I have uploaded the `.arff` file and the code for `DatasetLoading`, perhaps if you have the time you can have  alook?

Comment: You're outputting `z` inside the loop, instead of outside after processing all the instances.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response you've saved me so much time from having to figure out how to take the maximum value/ last value, as I was having many difficulties trying to have it to work!